# How to get pointer to buffer to read the contents and check the remaining data

Tags: c++, pointers

I am doing an application in c++ in which i need to use pointer to read the contents of the buffer. I used the following code to declare pointer to the buffer.

unsigned char *ptrToBuf = gchOBDReplyBuf;

The buffer has the data from a text file in it.
My question is how can i read the contents of this buffer using pointers? Also each time i need to check the buffer remaining contents as I need to exit when the buffer data have been fully read.Please help as I am not familiar with the contents of pointers..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do not use pointers for the sake of using. The power of pointers cannot be just explained by the above question. Get yourself familiar with the concepts of references and pointers before applying.

Answer (score 1):

Read a good C++ book that covers pointers in detail. The problem simply seems to be that you don't understand how to use pointers. The solution is to learn how to use them. Really, it's that simple. There's no point in someone typing out an explanation of pointers just for you, given that your question is non-specific.

Comment: I am new to c++. so the concept of pointers is little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i read the contents of this buffer using pointers?

You can access it as an array. `ptrToBuf[0]` is the first byte of the buffer, `ptrToBuff[1]` is the second, etc. Alternatively, for more "pointer-like" syntax, you can use `*ptrToBuff`, `*(ptrToBuff + 1)`, `*(ptrToBuff + 2)`, etc.

> Also each time i need to check the buffer remaining contents as I need to exit when the buffer data have been fully read.

To do this you would need to know either the length of the buffer, or know that the buffer is null-terminated. Are either of these the case?

Comment: Ok so each time i need to check if the buffer is null terminated or not?

Comment: _Assuming_ that this buffer is indeed null-terminated, you can constantly check whether the current character is equal to `'\0'`.

Comment: Ok could you please make clear the above mentioned point to read the contents of buffer using pointers?? I didnt understand the concept *(ptrToBuff + 1), Actually what is the difference between ptrToBuff[1] and *(ptrToBuf + 1)

Comment: There is no difference between those two things. `a[i]` is really just syntactic sugar for `*(a + i)`.

Comment: Ok Its working. But now i have to pass this pointer (ptrToBuf) to another buffer(gchOBDResponseBuf) in another class which is c++ class.I did it in following way and caused error:

CMainFrame *myframe; 
 myframe=(CMainFrame *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd; 
 CECUSimulatorView *myview; 
 myview=(CECUSimulatorView *)myframe->GetActiveView(); 

 gchOBDResponseBuf = myview->ptrToBuf;

I am getting compilation error as:

: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned char [4100]'

why is it sooo?? Please Help

Comment: That assignment won't actually copy the data, it will just change `gchOBDResponseBuf` so that it points to your other buffer (or rather, it will attempt to, but will fail because you can't actually overwrite a statically declared array as in `unsigned char something[4100]`. To copy the data, loop over the one buffer and move its contents to the other.